# Python - Exception handling for regex functions

Tags: python, regex, exception, match, text-mining

First time to the site, searched everywhere for an appropriate answer, let me know if my format is not correct.

**QUESTION**:
How do I apply exception handling when applying regex formulas to a Python dataframe?

**EXAMPLE**:
I am trying to obtain the second element after a `re.split` is applied. If the split delimiter is not present, Python returns an error - how do I overcome that?

**SCRIPT**:

```
test = ["abc-123", "abc123"]
[re.split("\-", str(x))[1] for x in test]
```

**WHAT I WANT**:
Preferably in the same line where the `re.split` happens, return the original string "abc123" (rather than an error) even when the "-" is not present and the split cannot happen.

THANKS!

Comment: no, python doesn't return an error. And exception is *raised* from the `.split` method, which you if you want to  handle it you use a `try-except`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
TEST = ["abc-123", "abc123"]
cleaned_test = [*map(lambda x: re.sub('.*-', '', x), TEST)]
print(cleaned_test)
```